# как вывести в Blade.php все картинки добавленные через multiple images ? Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.8

в воягер voyager выбрал поле multiple images
при таком получении

```html
<div class="slider single-product-nav">
                                        
   <div class="images-slide-single"> <img src="{{Voyager::image($page->images) }}" alt=""> 
   </div>
                                        
                                       
</div>
```

выводит:

```html
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/[&quot;products//February2020//orLYrsTYAOJoqVwLei62.jpg&quot;,&quot;products//February2020//BLdrXI8umJqDzxjdmuF5.jpg&quot;]" alt="">
```

спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($page->images as $image)
    <img src="{{Voyager::image($image) }}">
@endforeach
```

Код не тестировал, но думаю что суть ясна. У вас в `$page->images` находится массив картинок, а вам нужно сделать цикл по этому массиву и вывести каждое изображение

Comment: я так пробовал выводить почему то
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/professor/tiger/resources/views/product.blade.php)

Comment: Прикрепите код который вы пробовали

Comment: <div class="slider single-product-nav">
                                        @foreach($page->images as $image)
                                            <div class="images-slide-single"> <img src="{{ Voyager::image($image) }}" alt=""> </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                       
                                    </div>

Comment: @junior сделайте dump($page->images)

Comment: "["products\/February2020\/orLYrsTYAOJoqVwLei62.jpg","products\/February2020\/BLdrXI8umJqDzxjdmuF5.jpg"]"

Comment: Стоп это у вас массив записан в виде строки?

Comment: не знаю наверно, я просто выбрал  multiple images в админке и все